# Помогите с элементарным: выравнить текст по центру по вертикали в таблице

Tags: html

Есть таблица с ячейками, строками - все, как мы привыкли.
Прописывал в td теги, которые должны были разместить текст по центру. Тоже самое дклал с tr.

Как вы понимвете, результата нужного мне я не лостиг. Помогите, что такого крутого надо прописать, чтобы иеаст в таблице встал ровно по центру.

Скрин, как бонус для воображения.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приведите пример кода, который, как минимум, можно использовать для подготовки ответа

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Чуть позже добавлю. Сейчас с мобильного. Нет такой возможности.

Answer (score 0):

```
td {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Не работает такой вариант. Что-то блокирует. Не могу понять что

Comment: @Николай, у Вас текст, небось, в теги p обёрнут, а у тегов p по умолчанию нижний margin имеется, он и не даёт выровнять

Comment: Благодарю за совет. Сейчас проверю